# How to set and input an Expiration Date from Creation Date to database in Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Im trying to submit entries to database with automatic expiration date calculated +1 week after the creation date. The problem is, i don't know how to add the variable i made in the store controller to be created together with the inputs on the create form.

This is my create form :

```
                <div class="container-fluid">

                    <!-- Page Heading -->
                    <h1 class="h3 mb-2 text-gray-800">Pasien Baru</h1>
                    <p class="mb-4">Konfigurasi untuk mendaftarkan pasien</p>
                    
                    <div>
                        <form method="post" action="/dashboard/pasien" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            @csrf
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="nik">NIK Pasien</label>
                                <input maxlength="16" type="text" class="form-control @error('nik') is-invalid @enderror" id="nik" name="nik" placeholder="Nomor Induk Kependudukan">
                                @error ('nik')
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                        {{ $message }}
                                    </div>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="name">Nama Pasien</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Nama Lengkap">
                                @error ('name')
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                        {{ $message }}
                                    </div>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="lahir">Tanggal Lahir</label>
                                <input type="date" class="form-control @error('lahir') is-invalid @enderror" id="lahir" name="lahir">
                                @error ('lahir')
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                        {{ $message }}
                                    </div>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="kelamin">Jenis Kelamin</label><br>
                                <select class="form-select" name="kelamin" style="width: 200px">
                                    <option selected value="pasien">Laki-laki</option>
                                    <option value="admin">Perempuan</option>
                                </select>
                                @error ('kelamin')
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                        {{ $message }}
                                    </div>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="poli">Layanan</label><br>
                                <select class="form-select" name="poli" style="width: 200px">
                                    @foreach ($layanan as $poli)
                                        <option value="{{ $poli->singkatan }}">{{ $poli->jenis }}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                                @error ('poli')
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                        {{ $message }}
                                    </div>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="bayar">Jenis Pembayaran</label><br>
                                <select class="form-select" name="bayar" style="width: 200px">
                                    <option selected value="umum">Umum</option>
                                    <option value="bpjs">BPJS Kesehatan</option>
                                    <option value="kis">JKN-KIS</option>
                                </select>
                                @error ('bayar')
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                        {{ $message }}
                                    </div>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                            

                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-4">Daftarkan</button>
                        </form>
                        <a href="/dashboard/pasien/" class="mt-3 btn btn-danger">Batal</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

This is my laravel store controller. The $expiry_day is working fine, but i dont know how to add it together in the create method. I want so that the $expiry_day become the 'expired' value :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{                      
    $start_day = Carbon::parse($request->created_at);
    $expiry_day = $start_day->addWeek();
    
    $validateData = $request->validate([
        'nik' => 'required',
        'name' => 'required',
        'kelamin' => 'required',
        'lahir' => 'required',
        'bayar' => 'required',
        'expired' => 'required',
        'poli' => 'required',
    ]);
                      
    pasien::create($validateData);

    return redirect('/dashboard/pasien')->with('success','Data pasien berhasil ditambahkan');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add date to the validated data array. This will then be inserted when you create the model.

```
$validatedData = $request->validate([...]);

$start_day = Carbon::parse($request->created_at);
$validatedData['expired'] = $start_day->addWeek();

pasien::create($validateData);
```

This requires that `expired` is a column in the database and is in the fillable array on the `Pasien` model.

Bonus: please don't call classes in lowercase, it is universal agreed upon that classes starts with a capital letter.

```
Pasien::create($validateData);
```